# Multidimensional vs Jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have used a MultiDimesional Array as follows

```
  string[,] Columns = { { "clientA", "clientB" }}

    if (Columns.Length != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Columns.Length / 2; i++)
                {
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(Columns[i, 0], Columns[i, 1]);
                }
            }
```

After code analysis I got warning message as

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CA1814  'Order.GetLastOrderID()' uses a multidimensional array of  
'string[,]'. Replace it with a jagged array if possible.
```

I have researched jagged arrays on internet but How do I replace my array with jagged array.

Comment: can you share GetLastOrderID() code

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev actullly the array I used are sql  parameters which passed to a method.

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev edited some code , please see

Comment: You should ignore (and suppress) the message if your data is tabular and most cells are filled. Your code is fine. [The MSDN page for that warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182277.aspx) gives the rationale that it may waste space if the rows have different lengths. But given that strings are reference types, the waste isn't substantial, if there is any at all.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider yes, but I was just curious, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jagged array is an array of arrays, so you change your definition to:

```
string[][] Columns = { new string[] { "clientA", "clientB" }};
```

Change array access from...

```
var value = Columns[0,0];
```

...to...

```
var value = Columns[0][0];
```

You also have the option to suppress the warning (right-click on it and select the option you need). [According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182277.aspx), this is a warning that is safe to suppress in certain cases. Check if yours is such a case before you change the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 string[][] Columns = { 
     new string[] { "ClientA", "ClientB" } 
 };
```

If you need to add more elements to the array, it should look like this:

```
string[][] Columns = { 
    new string[] { "ClientA", "ClientB" },
    new string[] { "ClientC", "ClientD" },
    new string[] { "ClientE", "ClientF" } 
};
```

Then you can access each element with the code below

```
Columns[0][0] // Client A
Columns[0][1] // Client B
Columns[1][0] // Client C
Columns[1][1] // Client D
// etc.
```