# Using foreach loop for the first time and can't seem to get this right even though it says everywhere online that the code is correct

Tags: c#

Dont understand what's the problem here, I have been trying to trouble shoot this for half an hour. First time using foreach loop, and I am getting a cannot convert type 'char' to 'char[]' what does this mean? pretty new to programming.

```
namespace X_O_spel {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            char[,] spelBoard = new char[,] { {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}, 
                                              {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'}, 
                                              {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
                                              {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'}, 
                                              {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},};

            foreach(char[] row in spelBoard) {
                foreach(char c in row) {
                    Console.Write(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multidimensional vs Jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763839/multidimensional-vs-jagged-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a multidimensional array when you really want to be using a jagged array. Change `char[,]` to `char[][]` and you're code works:

```
char[][] spelBoard = new[]{ 
            new[]{' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}, 
            new[]{'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'}, 
            new[]{' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
            new[]{'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'}, 
            new[]{' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}};

foreach(char[] row in spelBoard)
{
    foreach(char c in row)
    {
        Console.Write(c);
    }
}
```

More information:

- [multidimensional-vs-jagged-array (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763839/multidimensional-vs-jagged-array)
- [multidimensional-arrays (ms-docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)
- [jagged-arrays (ms-docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays).

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhh ok, i understand. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Khaled Glad I could help. You should upvote and accept the answer to mark your question as solved if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get a char array from your result, i believe you would have an easier time just storing rows of strings.

```
        string[] spelBoard = new string[] {" | | ",
                                           "-+-+-", 
                                          " | | ",
                                          "-+-+-", 
                                          " | | "};

        foreach(string row in spelBoard) {
                Console.WriteLine(row);
            }
```

and of course if you need to, you could still treat row like a char array.

```
   foreach(char c in row)
{
    Console.Write(c);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really matter.

Comment: you're correct.  The initializer isn't compiling.

Comment: code is correct (and totally changed) now

Answer (score 0):

You're using a multidimensional array as if it were a jagged array.

Multidimensional: matrix.

Jagged: Array of arrays.

> A jagged array is an array whose elements are arrays. The elements of a jagged array can be of different dimensions and sizes.

You can solve declaring

```
char[][] spelBoard = new char {
    new char[] {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
    new char[] {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'}, 
    ...};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 { {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}, 
   {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'}, 
   {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
   {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'}, 
   {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}}
```

is not `char[,]` but it is `char[][]`, so change your code like:

```
 char[][] spelBoard = new char[][] { {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}, 
                                              {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'}, 
                                              {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
                                              {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'}, 
                                              {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete working example:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[][] spelBoard = {
                new[]{' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
                new[]{'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'},
                new[]{' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
                new[]{'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'},
                new[]{' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}};

            foreach (char[] row in spelBoard)
            {
                foreach (char c in row)
                {
                    Console.Write(c);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The help is much appreciated.